# SQLalchemy find id and use it to lookup other information

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm making a simple lookup application for Japanese characters (Kanji), where the user can search the database using any of the information available.

### My database structure

**Kanji**:

- id
- character (A kanji like 頑)
- heisig6 (a number indicating the order of showing Kanji)
- kanjiorigin (a number indicating the order of showing Kanji)

**MeaningEN** (1 kanji_id can have multiple entries with different meanings):

- kanji_id (FOREIGN KEY(kanji_id) REFERENCES "Kanji" (id)
- meaning

### User handling

The user can choose to search by 'id', 'character', 'heisig6', 'kanjiorigin' or 'meaning' and it should then return all information in all those fields. (All fields return only 1 result, except meanings, which can return multiple results)

### Code, EDIT 4+5: my code with thanks to @ApolloFortyNine and #sqlalchemy on IRC, EDIT 6: `join` --> `outerjoin` (otherwise won't find information that has no Origins)

```
import sqlalchemy as sqla
import sqlalchemy.orm as sqlo
from tableclass import TableKanji, TableMeaningEN, TableMisc, TableOriginKanji  # See tableclass.py

# Searches database with argument search method
class SearchDatabase():
    def __init__(self):
        #self.db_name = "sqlite:///Kanji_story.db"
        self.engine = sqla.create_engine("sqlite:///Kanji.db", echo=True)

        # Bind the engine to the metadata of the Base class so that the
        # declaratives can be accessed through a DBSession instance
        tc.sqla_base.metadata.bind = self.engine

        # For making sessions to connect to db
        self.db_session = sqlo.sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)

    def retrieve(self, s_input, s_method):
        # s_input: search input
        # s_method: search method
        print("\nRetrieving results with input: {} and method: {}".format(s_input, s_method))

        data = []  # Data to return

        # User searches on non-empty string
        if s_input:
            session = self.db_session()

            # Find id in other table than Kanji
            if s_method == 'meaning':
                s_table = TableMeaningEN  # 'MeaningEN'
            elif s_method == 'okanji':
                s_table = TableOriginKanji  # 'OriginKanji'
            else:
                s_table = TableKanji  # 'Kanji'

            result = session.query(TableKanji).outerjoin(TableMeaningEN).outerjoin(
                (TableOriginKanji, TableKanji.origin_kanji)
            ).filter(getattr(s_table, s_method) == s_input).all()
            print("result: {}".format(result))
            for r in result:
                print("r: {}".format(r))

                meanings = [m.meaning for m in r.meaning_en]
                print(meanings)
                # TODO transform into origin kanji's
                origins = [str(o.okanji_id) for o in r.okanji_id]
                print(origins)

                data.append({'character': r.character, 'meanings': meanings,
                             'indexes': [r.id, r.heisig6, r.kanjiorigin], 'origins': origins})

            session.close()

        if not data:
            data = [{'character': 'X', 'meanings': ['invalid', 'search', 'result']}]
        return(data)
```

### Question EDIT 4+5

- Is this an efficient query?: `result = session.query(TableKanji).join(TableMeaningEN).filter(getattr(s_table, s_method) == s_input).all()` (The .join statement is necessary, because otherwise e.g. `session.query(TableKanji).filter(TableMeaningEN.meaning == 'love').all()` returns all the meanings in my database for some reason? So is this either the right query or is my `relationship()` in my tableclass.py not properly defined?
- **fixed** (see `lambda:` in tableclass.py) `kanji = relationship("TableKanji", foreign_keys=[kanji_id], back_populates="OriginKanji")` <-- **what is wrong** about this? It gives the error:

  File "/*path*/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1805, in get_property
   "Mapper '%s' has no property '%s'" % (self, key))

  sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Mapper 'Mapper|TableKanji|Kanji' has no property 'OriginKanji'

### Edit 2: tableclass.py (EDIT 3+4+5: updated)

```
import sqlalchemy as sqla
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative as sqld

sqla_base = sqld.declarative_base()


class TableKanji(sqla_base):
    __tablename__ = 'Kanji'

    id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, primary_key=True)
    character = sqla.Column(sqla.String, nullable=False)
    radical = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer)  # Can be defined as Boolean
    heisig6 = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, unique=True, nullable=True)
    kanjiorigin = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, unique=True, nullable=True)
    cjk = sqla.Column(sqla.String, unique=True, nullable=True)

    meaning_en = relationship("TableMeaningEN", back_populates="kanji")  # backref="Kanji")
    okanji_id = relationship("TableOriginKanji", foreign_keys=lambda: TableOriginKanji.kanji_id, back_populates="kanji")

class TableMeaningEN(sqla_base):
    __tablename__ = 'MeaningEN'

    kanji_id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, sqla.ForeignKey('Kanji.id'), primary_key=True)
    meaning = sqla.Column(sqla.String, primary_key=True)

    kanji = relationship("TableKanji", back_populates="meaning_en")


class TableOriginKanji(sqla_base):
    __tablename__ = 'OriginKanji'

    kanji_id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, sqla.ForeignKey('Kanji.id'), primary_key=True)
    okanji_id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, sqla.ForeignKey('Kanji.id'), primary_key=True)
    order = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer)

    #okanji = relationship("TableKanji", foreign_keys=[kanji_id], backref="okanji")
    kanji = relationship("TableKanji", foreign_keys=[kanji_id], back_populates="okanji_id")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would really have to be able to see your database schema to give real critique, but assuming no foreign keys, what you said is basically the best you can do.

SQLAlchemy really begins to shine when you have complicated relations going on however. For example, if you properly had foreign keys set, you could do something like the following.

```
# Assuming kanji is a tc.tableMeaningEN.kanji_id object
kanji_meaning = kanji.meanings
```

And that would return the meanings for the kanji as an array, without any further queries.

You can go quite deep with relationships, so I'm linking the documentation here. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html

EDIT: Actually, you don't need to manually join at all, SQLAlchemy will do it for you.

The case is wrong on your classes, but I'm not sure if SQLAlchemy is case sensitive there or not. If it works, then just move on.

If you query the a table (self.session.query(User).filter(User.username == self.name).first()) you should have an object of the table type (User here).

So in your case, querying the TableKanji table alone will return an object of that type.

```
kanji_obj = session.query(TableKanji).filter(TableKanji.id == id).first()
# This will return an array of all meaning_ens that match the foreign key
meaning_arr = kanji_obj.meaning_en
# This will return a single meeting, just to show each member of the arr is of type TableMeaningEn
meaning_arr[0].meaning
```

I have a project made use of some of these features, hope it helps:
https://github.com/ApolloFortyNine/SongSense
Database declaration (with relationships): https://github.com/ApolloFortyNine/SongSense/blob/master/songsense/database.py
Automatic joins: https://github.com/ApolloFortyNine/SongSense/blob/master/songsense/getfriend.py#L134

I really like my database structure, but as for the rest it's pretty awful. Hope it still helps though.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will dive some deeper into foreign keys and relationships.

Comment: I added the relationships (see tableclass.py) and tried a 3rd time (see `def retrieve3()`. However I still don't get the results back in the format I want. I don't know how to set kanji as a tc.tableMeaningEN.kanji_id object.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it answers my original question. However if you have time, please see if you can answer what's 'Question'. It seems I needed to use the .join, see 'Question'. p.s. SQLAlchemy is case sensitive, I just didn't properly updated my code when I followed your CamelCase recommendation.

Comment: It is odd that it lets you actually run that query, but I believe the issue is the relationship returns the whole object, not just one column. Therefore, a call TableKanji.meaning_en returns a TableMeaningEn object. Also, since you didn't set a single parent to be true (which is okay considering your data), TableKanji.meaning_en should always return an array.

In this case I normally would query TableMeaningEn for meaning='love', then access the .kanji property of the returned objects to get the Kanji meaning.

Comment: As for the second part of your question, back_populates requires you to create the property in the other table that will link back. Backref autocreates this for you, so I would just switch over to it instead. Also, you don't need to specify the foreign key in probably 99% of cases. It's mostly used if you are doing a join and for some reason didn't create a foreign key constraint.

Also, by Kanji meaning in the answer above I meant an instance of the TableKanji object.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been with `.meaning`, because this `getattr(s_table, s_method) == s_input` turns in to `TableMeaningEN.meaning == 'love'`, so I queried by meaning, but that returns all meanings without if I don't add the .join(TableMeaningEN)?

Comment: Fixed `relationship()` between `TableKanji` and `TableOriginKanji`